# Display parent directory for all subdirectories (.htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess

Here's what I am trying to do:

I have a directory **/myDirectory/** which points to **/myDirectory/index.php**

I want all subdirectories such as **/myDirectory/ABC** to point to **/myDirectory/index.php** without any redirection.

What is the .htaccess file I need to write?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following Rule in your `/subfolder/.htaccess` if you do not have an htaccess file in your subfolder you can create one and add  the following rule :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.+$ /subfolder/index.php  [L]
```